# height in percentage in html

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

```
    body{
         height:100%;
         background-color:white;
        }
    .div1{
         float:left;cursor:pointer;margin:0.2%;background-color:maroon;text-decoration:none;width:18%;height:50%;text-align: center;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank"><div class="div1"><h1>Block0</h1><p>
    It is a floating Block0</p></div></a>

<a href="https://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank"><div class="div1"><h1>Block1</h1><p>
    It is a floating Block1</p></div></a>
```

here if I provide height in pixels it works, I including height for 'body'  as you can see. But it is not working. can you suggest what's wrong? also i forgot to mention I use thi code in sharepoint. The code wrks fine in browser but in sharepoint the size wont change.

Comment: Add HTML to height: 100% -> body,html{ height: 100%;}

Comment: No change... :( width is changing when I change it, but its only the height which is unchangeable.

Comment: What you can't get it work? This jsfiddle show that is working the height: 100% and the blocks are 50% -- https://jsfiddle.net/w53wk3va/

Answer (score 0):

add height:100; to html,body,a
i.e.

```
body,html,a{
    height:100%;
}
```

and display:block; to a
i.e.

```
a{
    display:block;
}
```

and change height of .div1 to 100%
You will get what you need

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h01sges0/